# Cannot load dataset pytorchvideo.data.Kinetics

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I've been trying for the last few days to run a script for training ml model. I trying to debug on every possible way what is going on but the error I'm getting is so obscure. I can't debug which file is corrupted. I assuming that the problem is in my dataset structure. I will be glad for mentions of working datasets or examples.

I'm trying to run this example [Training a PyTorchVideo classification model](https://pytorchvideo.org/docs/tutorial_classification). I was also trying to download kinetics dataset but tutorial of how to do it is made that way that it throws errors [Kinetics - Downloader](https://github.com/activitynet/ActivityNet/tree/master/Crawler/Kinetics). I'm frustrated beyond measurement.

**error which I get:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2da0ffaf5447> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train()

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pytorchvideo/data/labeled_video_dataset.py in __next__(self)
    223             return sample_dict
    224         else:
--> 225             raise RuntimeError(
    226                 f"Failed to load video after {self._MAX_CONSECUTIVE_FAILURES} retries."
    227             )

RuntimeError: Failed to load video after 10 retries.
```

**My code:**

```
class KineticsDataModule(pytorch_lightning.LightningDataModule):

  # Dataset configuration
  _DATA_PATH = 'drive/MyDrive/dataset/'
  _CLIP_DURATION = 2  # Duration of sampled clip for each video
  _BATCH_SIZE = 8
  _NUM_WORKERS = 2  # Number of parallel processes fetching data


  def train_dataloader(self):
    """
    Create the Kinetics train partition from the list of video labels
    in {self._DATA_PATH}/train.csv. Add transform that subsamples and
    normalizes the video before applying the scale, crop and flip augmentations.
    """
    print('banan')
    train_transform = Compose(
        [
        ApplyTransformToKey(
          key="video",
          transform=Compose([])
          ),
        ]
    )
    train_dataset = pytorchvideo.data.Kinetics(
        data_path=os.path.join(self._DATA_PATH, "train.txt"),
        clip_sampler=pytorchvideo.data.make_clip_sampler("random", self._CLIP_DURATION),
        transform=train_transform
    )
    return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=self._BATCH_SIZE,
        num_workers=self._NUM_WORKERS,
    )

  def val_dataloader(self):
    """
    Create the Kinetics validation partition from the list of video labels
    in {self._DATA_PATH}/val
    """

    print('cytrynka')
    val_transform = Compose(
        [
        ApplyTransformToKey(
          key="video",
          transform=Compose([])
          ),
        ]
    )

    val_dataset = pytorchvideo.data.Kinetics(
        data_path=os.path.join(self._DATA_PATH, "validation.txt"),
        clip_sampler=pytorchvideo.data.make_clip_sampler("uniform", self._CLIP_DURATION),
        transform=val_transform
    )

    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        val_dataset,
        batch_size=self._BATCH_SIZE,
        num_workers=self._NUM_WORKERS,
    )

    # Iterate through the DataLoader and print information about each batch
    for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(val_dataset):
      try:
          videos = batch["video"]
          # Your processing code here
      except RuntimeError as e:
          print(f"Error loading video in batch {batch_idx}: {e}")

    return val_dataloader
```